# '-[FBLPromise pendingObjects]: unrecognized selector sent...' Crash on Integrating reCAPTCHA Enterprise with iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

So I direct downloaded the framework and followed all the steps listed here https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps#direct-download.

But when I run the project it throws `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise pendingObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002eb8c90'`. For those who are unaware FBLPromise is one of the dependencies on reCAPTCHA framework.

Did anyone face the same problem? or know a way out on how to resolve the same?

Comment: have you added FBLPromises.xcframework ?

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. But issue was due to accessibility of my google account. this got resolved once access was provided. Thanks for chipping in @MohammedShakeer I believe reCAPTCHA framework internally doenloads the required dependencies

Comment: Do u find solution? I have same problem

Comment: Yup like I mentioned! I did not have the correct access. 
Once the Security team added my credentials correctly in the Recaptcha Enterprise, I was able to proceed with further steps